# mailto: link in Chrome on Android opens about:blank tab and not default email program

Tags: android, google-chrome, mailto

Searched high and low for an answer to this. The code looks like:

```
href="mailto:?to=&subject=This is my subject&body=http://www.example.com/"
```

Tested in Chrome, Safari, Firefox and several other smaller browsers on iPhone and Android. Works on one of my Galaxy S4 test phones, but not on my S3 or Note3.

There are some older "fixes" out there about editing handlers via chrome://settings/handlers, but this seems to be out of date.